# A cyclic group of order $n$ has a subgroup of order $d$ for every divisor $d$ of $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G = \langle a \rangle$ be a cyclic group of order $n$. Show that for every divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists a subgroup $G$ whose order is $d$.

If $d \mid n$ then there exists $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $n = md$. Since $a^n = 1_G$, we have $a^{md} = (a^m)^d = 1_G $. How to proceed from here? We have that $a^m$ is an element of order $d$, but do I still have to prove that there is a subgroup $G$ with arbitrary elements of the form $a^m$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$ has order $d$.

Comment: $ a^n = a^{n(d/d)} = (a^{n/d})^d $ right? Thanks for the hint

Comment: Yes, but you also have to show that if $(a^{\frac{n}{d}})^e=1$, then $d \mid e$.

Comment: Isn't $e $ equal to $1$? You used both

Comment: $e$ is here just a natural number - not 2.7182818 ... :-)). In this case the order of $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$. You have to check if $d|e$ and $e|d$, whence $e=d$. In group theory the identity element is denoted as $1$ (that is what I use mostly), $e$, $1_G$.

Comment: So we have to show that $ d $ is a natural number essentially?

Comment: No, no, that is not necessary. I put $e$ as the order of $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$, so $e$ is by definition the smallest natural number such that $(a^{\frac{n}{d}})^e=1$. You already showed that $(a^{\frac{n}{d}})^d=1$, and this implies $e \mid d$ (can you see why?). Conversely, $(a^{\frac{n}{d}})^e=1$, but since $n$ is the order of $a$, we get $n \mid \frac{ne}{d}$, say $\frac{ne}{d}=fn$. This implies $e=df$, whence $d \mid e$. But we already had $e \mid d$, so $d=e$ is the order of $a^{\frac{n}{d}}$. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: This makes it clear, thank you

Comment: @StVincent the claim in the Hint is also proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3306841/242), slightly more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

Just consider the cyclic subgroup generated by $a^m$.