# $\operatorname{ord}(a)=km$ implies $\operatorname{ord}(a^k)=m$

Tags: abstract-algebra

For this proof, is it simply that $\operatorname{ord}(a)=km$ says be definition that $a^{km}=e$, so $\operatorname{ord}(a^k)=x$, so $a^{kx}=e$, giving $m=x$?

Comment: $\operatorname{ord}(a)=km$ means that by definition $a^{km}=e$, you are right about that. We can rewrite $a^{km}=\left(a^k\right)^m$ which is also equal to $e$. This means that the order of $a^k$ is $m$.

Comment: Well, you know that it is at most $m$, then you need to show that it is at least $m$ (which is just as easy).

Comment: For reference, this is Pinter 10.D.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $k$ and $m$ be positive integers. From $\text{ord}(a)=km$, we can see that $a^{km}=(a^k)^m=e$.

It follows that $a^k$ has order **less than or equal** to $m$. But we must show that $a^k$ has order **exactly** $m$.

Suppose to the contrary that $a^k$ has order  $l\lt m$. Then $a^{kl}=e$. Since $kl\lt km$, this contradicts the fact that $a$ has order $km$.

Comment: Why do you say "less than or equal to?" Why isn't the equality immediate since I know that $(a^k)^m=e$?

Comment: Think of $\mathbb Z_5$. I know that $(\bar 4)^{50} = \overline {200} = \bar 0$ but that does not mean $o(\bar 4) = 50$, just that the order is at most $50$ (and more strongly, that it divides $50$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I haven't seen that notation before. I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: ;Example: Look at the group whose elements are $1,2,3,4$ under multiplication modulo $5$. Note that $2^{12}=1$. But $12$ is not the order of $2$, since the smallest positive $s$ such that $2^s=1$ is $s=4$. When we say that an element $a$ has order $q$, we are saying **two** things: (i) $a^q=e$ and (ii) there is no positive $s\lt q$ such that $a^s=e$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense!

Comment: The order of an element $b$ of finite order is by definition the **smallest** positive integer $q$ such that $b^q=e$. So to show $b$ has order $q$, we must show two things, (i) $b^q=e$ and (ii) nothing smaller than $q$ "works."

Comment: In your proof, should you have $a^{kl}=e$ and since $kl<km$, we have a contradiction?

Comment: @Moz: Thank you, fixed. You really do understand it!

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Very simple and direct solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $\:{\rm ord}(a) = KM\:$ [then](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,(\color{#0a0}{a^{ K}})^{\color{#c00}{J}}\! = 1\!\iff KM\mid KJ\iff M\mid\color{#c00} J,\ $ [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127118/242) $\,{\rm ord}(\color{#0a0}{a^{K}})= M$

Comment: I'm reviewing this proof and am looking at your approach. I'm trying to understand what the [theorem you link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127109/order-of-an-element-modulo-n-divides-phin) to is saying. What does `ϕ(n)` mean? At first I read the theorem as: `ord(a) mod n | ord(n)` or `ord(a mod n) | ord(n)` but not sure those even make sense. Yay, math and all the different notations. :-)

Comment: @dharmatech In that question $\varphi$ denotes [Euler's totient function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), thus $\large \, a^{\large \varphi}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, o(a)\mid\varphi.\,$ Note: in that answer  $\,\rm n\,$ does not denote the modulus  (there is no need to mention the modulus there).

Answer (score -1):

It's well-known that for any element (of finite order) of a group, $\mid a^l\mid =m/(m,l),$ where $m=\mid a\mid. $  Here's a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4484127/1070376).

So, we get $\mid a\mid=km\implies \mid a^k\mid=km/(km,k)=km/k=m.$